# Python KIVY - Installed 1.9.1 but can't seem to work?

Tags: python, installation, kivy

I have successfully installed Kivy 1.9.1's wheel, using PIP, onto Python 3.4.3......however, when I am trying to run a sample program, the program is throwing errors.

I am running this program/using Kivy to try and learn from a Udemy course. The program should just pop a button on the screen and let you click it, showing you everything was installed. I believe I've installed it correctly but I'm wondering if I have missed maybe installing an extra package to support it, etc? Any help is great appreciated. Here's the sample code just to see if it runs, and the error below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''

BoxLayout:
    Button: b1


'''))

[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Codie\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-11-19_23.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Codie\Desktop\PythonKIVY-3.4pyFiles\Kivytesting.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys, for future reference:

Make sure you have EVERY package installed, glew, sdl2, gstream, etc. Then it will work :)